# Workaround for poor multithreaded performance of localtime_s() on Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

It seems like `localtime_s()` (which is the equivalent of the standard `localtime_r`) contains a critical section in MSVC.

For comparison, here are 2 sample apps, one does `localtime_s` in a loop, the other `gmtime_s`.

- http://rextester.com/OQJ48177
- http://rextester.com/JNDR45936

Profiling shows heavy lock contention inside `isindst` called from `common_localtime_s<__int64>`:

[image: localtime lock contention]

`gmtime` does not exhibit the issue:

[image: gmtime no lock contention]

Is there any way to work around this to get sane `localtime_s` performance in a multithreaded environment, provided I do need local times in my process?

Comment: Do you actually call this function often enough that it is a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, it currently takes up 70% of all elapsed time (64 CPUs).

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same problem. localtime_s is slow in multithreaded environment. I was not able to find a solution for it.

Comment: Have you considered calculating the offset from `gmtime` and `localtime` and then just apply that offset to the time returned by `gmtime`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Updating the offset every full hour should also prevent problems with daylight saving changes.

Comment: The lock protects some static variables used to cache the result of the DST calculation. Not much you can do about that. You'll probably have to use an alternate implementation of the conversion if you cannot work off an offset as recommended. Note that `_localtime64_s` also calls `__tzset`, which takes a number of locks as well, so I bet even if you work around `_isindst`, those will still bite you somewhat.

Comment: But `localtime` calculates the offset based on the input timestamp. If the input lies in DST, then it adds DST offset. Don't see an easy way to workaround that with a fixed offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one proposed solution:

Record all times in whatever is the fastest. When presenting them to a user through a GUI, a log file, or whatever, do the conversion to local time then.

Since most GUIs and log output are single threaded, this should remove the contention from the rest of the program.

If the program is never presenting data to a user, then just write it out in the fast time format and use a post-processing tool to convert it or display it.

Comment: Indeed I ended up using `gmtime` internally. But I also implemented `localtime_lockfree` by copying MS CRT implementation and making all `static` variables `thread_local` (and removing the locks of course). Unfortunately I can't share the resulting code as MSCRT license prohibits sharing modified sources :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the standard implementation uses locks and there is not an easy way around it, you'll probably have to use a different implementation. I would recommend trying to base it off of [`GetTimeZoneInformationForYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540851.aspx), which will provide you with the offset from UTC for both standard and DST time and the dates during which DST is active. You also have the option calling this once for each year you care about and caching the result for use by all your threads.

Since `gmtime_s` is performing acceptably, I would recommend you use this to obtain the year. (Note that this is what `localtime_s` does.) Subtract off the appropriate Bias value provided by `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear`, then use `gmtime_s` again to split it into the date components.

Comment: Very interesting. It seems like the implementation in MS CRT does not use this API but always uses the current timezone (`GetTimeZoneInformation`), so doing it this way can in fact be more accurate. BTW the CRT implementation also supports the `TZ` environment variable as an override.